C# App doesn't start up when running Appium WDA on iOS
We are using Appium to test our multi-platform app. (Windows, Android, iOS). This App is written using C# in .Net 8 with MVVMCross.
However, since about month or 2 ago, our App crashes on start up on iOS when the Appium xcuitest WebDriverAgent is running.
Looking into the logs and console, it's because the app is taking longer then 19 seconds to start up.
If the WebDriverAgent is not running, the app is starting in less then a second and it working fine.
This seems related to the exact .Net version, as this started happening when.net 8.0.303 was updated to .Net 8.0.401. But any attempt to downgrade to .Net 8.0.303 doesn't seem to make it work again, meaning either our downgrade isn't working or it's something else that was updated around the same time.
Does anyone have any idea what this could be?
Note: I have updated Apium and drivers to the latest version (and updated the WebDriverAgent on the iPhone as well).
Edit: Updating appium and it's drivers was part of the attempt to resolve this issue. It also stopped working with an older version so I don't think Appium directly is responsible for this not working anymore.
Edit2: We also just realized that the ios workload has received an update. We were on 8.0.300 and now it's 8.0.401. We also can't downgrade that on our build server to test unfortunately.

A full explanation can be found here:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/21234
But this is due to the "Window" in MvvmCross property being exported now where it wasn't before.
A work around is to remove the "initialViewController" attribute from your storyboard.
